# Report Syntax Errors Using register_shutdown_function Not Working

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have set up a function that catches fatal errors. If i add a call to an undefined function the code works fine. It also works when i use exit();, but it does not work if i have any syntax errors like missing semi colon.

```
register_shutdown_function( "reportFatalError" );

function reportFatalError()
{
    echo "error";
}

echo undefinedfuncton(); //works

echo "missing semi colon" //does not work
echo "next line";
```

How can i get this to work?

Comment: I'd imagine it wouldn't be able to parse that file, and thus not be able to register the shutdown. If you put the error in another file, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

List the types of errors
[Errors and Logging](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

this is example [Using error handling in a script](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.examples.php)